# Multiple columns after a WHERE in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Hey all, just a quick question (should be an easy fix I think).  In a WHERE statement in a query, is there a way to have multiple columns contained inside?  Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass'";
```

What I want to do is add another column after the WHERE (called priv_level = '$privlevel').  I wasn't sure of the syntax on how to do that however.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: see this question for why this is a bad idea and ways to do what you need safely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on SQL. But anyways, to do it just add `AND priv_level = '$privlevel'` to the end of the SQL.

This might be a pretty big step if you're new to PHP, but I think you should read up on the [`mysqli` class in PHP](http://se.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) too. It allows much safer execution of queries.

Otherwise, here's a safer way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE " .
       "username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($myusername) . "' AND " .
       "pwd = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($pass) . "' AND " .
       "priv_level = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($privlevel) . "'";
```

Comment: PDO is even better than mysqli

Comment: I must say I hadn't heard of PDO... But then again, last time I used PHP properly was about four years ago... Thanks for the tip! =)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped for legibility:

```
$sql="
  SELECT * 
  FROM $tbl_name 
  WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass' and priv_level = '$privlevel'
";
```

Someone else will warn you about how dangerous the statement is. :-) Think [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass' and priv_level = '$privlevel'";
```

If you prefer to not use ", try this:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM '.$tbl_name.' WHERE username=\''.$myusername.'\' and pwd=\''.$pass.'\' and priv_level=\''.$privlevel.'\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass' AND priv_level = '$privlevel'";
```

On a side note: what you appear to be doing here is quite bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add it (may be with AND) to the WHERE-clause:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass' and priv_level = '$privlevel'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, your query already uses multiple columns in the WHERE clause :)

SQL injection issues aside (be careful):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and pwd='$pass' and priv_level='$privlevel'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause can `AND` any number of checks, so you can easily have three where you not have two, just add `and priv_level='$priv_level'` at the very end.

Edit: as @thorarin's answer mention, this is a risky way to build up SQL queries, and parameter binding would be safer -- but that's orthogonal to using two vs three columns in the `WHERE` clause.